# нужна помощь с автокликером С++

Tags: c++, visual-studio

я написал простенький автокликер :

```
while (1) {

        int key = _getch();
        if (key == 89 || key == 121) {
            cout << "start in 5 seconds\n";

            POINT point; 
            GetCursorPos(&point);

            Sleep(5000);
            while (1) {
                if (GetAsyncKeyState(0x11)) {
                    break;
                }
                mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0);
                mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0);

                Sleep(10);  
            }
        }
```

подскажите как реализовать функцию нажатия кликера по заданному цвету пикселя. Есть допустим картинка. На ней белый фон и черная точка по середине. Мы указываем автокликеру hex черного цвета. и он ищет на экране этот цвет и нажимает на него.

Comment: Не совсем понятно, что именно должен делать аавтокликер... Он должен смотреть на цвет пикселя од мышкой? и каликать, когда этот цвет стал "таким то и таким то"?

Comment: Есть допустим картинка. На ней белый фон и черная точка по середине. Мы указываем автокликеру hex черного цвета. и он ищет на экране этот цвет и нажимает на него.

Comment: спасибо за пояснения. Может, добавите это объяснение в сам вопрос?